# Possibility of detecting language of email body by Email headers

Tags: java, email, mime, email-headers

Adding on one more query extending from here [Detecting language of email body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3447088/99917):

Since I want to determine the language of the email that I receive on my system, so that I can reply to the sender in same language.

So in the email headers there is one header of the kind:

'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1'

How good it can prove in determining the language of the email body?

e.g (all headers taken out from gmail):

1. for Chinese subject and body 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=GB2312'
2. for Korean subject and body 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=EUC-KR'
3. for french/italian subject and body 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'

Also is there any list somebody can direct me that have mappings defined for language to charset?

thanks in advance

Ashish

Comment: And most of the times, utf-8 means "terrestrial"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the required list](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset-lang.html)

I would suggest you to go for google api to detect language. as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447088/detecting-language-of-email-body)