# Handle different languages while parsing email from inbound email service in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have implemented an email service where I parse the email and create an opportunity record. It works perfect.

Now I have an issue in the following scenario:

Scenario:
email is sent from email address A to B,
from B it is forwarded to C (SF email address).
When an email is sent from address B, It is assumed as it has been forwarded by some other email address, I need that original email address.
So in that case I search for keywords ‘From’ , ‘To’, etc to find the actual email address (i.e. A). This also works perfectly fine.

The issue is:
the emails are sent from around the globe. So in some emails, the language is other that English.
For ex:

———- Weitergeleitete Nachricht ———-

Datum:

Betreff:

Absender:

An:

instead of

———- Forwarded message ———-

date:

subject:

sender:

to:

Please suggest how can I handle different languages?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to first identify the email language from the originating headers (this might be helpful: [Possibility of detecting language of email body by Email headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757861/possibility-of-detecting-language-of-email-body-by-email-headers))

Once you can accurately identify the incoming language you should be able to write parsers for each. Alternatively consider using a 3rd party parser tool with API?